# Function positive, negative, graph

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Given this function: $y=\frac{x^4-3}{4x-1}$

Studying the sign of the function I get that it's positive when $x<\frac{1}{4}∨x>\sqrt[4]{3}$ and negative in the other way. Then why is the graph negative even in the lower left?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is not complete. You have two roots $\pm \sqrt[4]{3}$...

Given function is negative for: $x< -\sqrt[4]{3}$ and ${1\over 4}<x<\sqrt[4]{3}$